# How to fetch the default domain with WPML active?

Tags: wordpress, wpml

For a plugin that I code, we use the domain name for the purpose of registering the premium licenses. We check this against our records or whatnot to ensure that they have that site registered and can therefore use the premium features of the plugin.

I'm finding, however, that when users are using WPML with different domains for each language, the registration only works on one default domain as that's the domain name being used for registration.

```
$domain = get_home_url();
```

This is essentially the function that I've been using to fetch that information.

Is there a way to fetch that url, but to always retrieve one, constant, default value regardless of which language subdomain is being loaded? Such that if they have French, Spanish, and English, and English is the default, it always returns the English domain?

Comment: What domain structure you use? //en.example.com or //example.com/en/ ?

Comment: This would be for subdomains (en.example.com), not subfolders (example.com/en/).

Comment: WPML have his own function icl_get_home_url(); 
But you need to check if WPML is active if ( function_exists('icl_object_id') ) {
     //something
}

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I was looking for. If you put that as an answer, I'll accept and upvote it. Thanks! But instead of checking for icl_object_id, would it be better to check for the specific function that you're recommending that I use (icl_get_home_url())? Or does that not really matter?

Comment: I found it on WPML documentation if icl_get_home_url() works - cool)

Answer (score 1):

Use icl_get_home_url(); function what recomends by WPML documentation.
Also, you need to check if WPML is installed and active.

You can do something like

```
$domain = get_home_url();

if ( function_exists('icl_object_id') ) { 
$domain = icl_get_home_url();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must have the same domain returned always, use `get_option( 'home' );` instead, icl_get_home_url() is deprecated and doesn't do what you are asking. At least not anymore... Currently, icl_get_home_url() returns the localized domain instead of the default, just like wpml_home_url(): https://wpml.org/documentation/support/creating-multilingual-wordpress-themes/home-page-link/

There is also WordPress Multi-site to account for though, so I'd recommend the following:

```
if ( is_multisite() ) {
    switch_to_blog( 1 );
    $url = get_option( 'home' );
    restore_current_blog();
} else {
    $url = get_option( 'home' );
}
```

This bypasses any filtering, and should ensure that you always get the primary url/domain for validation.